# Border-radius in JavaFX CSS not working on containers

Tags: css, javafx

I am using JavaFX 8 with css files.This is the look I am trying to achieve:
[image]

This is a card container. The drop-shadow works fine, but the corners remain, and a border is created on TOP of the card when I use border-radius, as such: [image]

This leaves the corners very apparent. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use borders. Css background instead.
Load the sample to SceneBuilder to get the idea.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>


<StackPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" style="-fx-background-color: silver;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <StackPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="300.0" style="-fx-background-color: purple, blue; -fx-background-radius: 8, 0; -fx-background-insets: 0, 4;">
         <effect>
            <DropShadow />
         </effect>
      </StackPane>
   </children>
</StackPane>
```

Comment: why do you need the insets?